# python - Proper way to find correlations between features containing missing data

Tags: python, correlation, missing-data, pearson

1) Most of the **features are NOT normally distributed**

- Just realized that [SciPy pearsonr](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.pearsonr.html) I used requires normal
  distribution (what's [indeed weird](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/3730/pearsons-or-spearmans-correlation-with-non-normal-data)).
- [Numpy.corrcoef](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.corrcoef.html) description says nothing about such requirements. Should I use it? Other recommendations?

2) **Features contain missing data** (less than 50% per feature), and I'd like to feel it later. I can't find how those modules handle None values. (Just see that in comparison with the same dataset filled with medians pearsonr > 0.7 finds 71 correlated features instead of 200+)

Everything is stored in pandas dataframe, so technically I pass list(df.column_name) to pearsonr.

---

**UPD:** 
Well, found **pandas.DataFrame.corr**:

- offers both *pearson, kendall, spearman*
- clearly says it's *excluding NA/null values*
- says nothing about requirements or other details

It's too seductive to deny, so I'll go with it (and Spearman as my friend who can into math stats recommends). But nevertheless - lazy pandas aren't always there for you.